# Placeholder text not centered for UITextField created programmatically

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I am creating a UITextField programmatically and placing it inside a UIView. The font size is set to 15.0f (system font). But the placeholder that appears is not centered in the text view. Any one know how to resolve this?

I found some references on SO for blurred text etc and tried setting the frame of the textfield with integer values, but it doesn't make a difference.

```
UITextField *txtField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0f, 6.0f, 278.0f, 32.0f)];
[txtField setPlaceholder:@"My placeholder"];
[txtField setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0]];
[txtField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
[txtField setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
[txtField setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone];
[txtField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress];
[txtField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
[txtField setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
```

Thank you for any help

**Note: I mean that the text is not centered vertically in the textfield (it is a bit towards the top). So setting the text alignment is not the solution.**

Adding an image of the issue for clarification - as seen in the image, the placeholder text is more towards the top and not in the center vertically.
[image]

Comment: +1 Thanks Your Question helped me..

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You need to add:

```
txtField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter; // Pre-iOS6 SDK: UITextAlignmentCenter
```

Keep in mind, this adjusts both the alignment of the placeholder text as well as the text the user will enter in.

**How to center vertically**

Since the original question was updated to request how to vertically align the placeholder text and that answer is buried in the comments, here is how to do that:

```
txtField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
```

Comment: Sorry about that. I guess the question was a bit mis-leading. I meant that the text is not centered vertically. Updated the question.

Comment: Then link us to a screenshot so we can see exactly what you're talking about. I've never seen this myself, and I've done this a fair bit.

Comment: Added the image as well. Please let me know if that helps in pin-pointing the issue. Not sure what I could be doing wrong. The method for creating a textfield is pretty straightforward!

Comment: Ah ok, I see what's going on. Try setting your text field's `contentVerticalAlignment` property to `UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter` that should fix you right up.

Comment: Shouldn't everyone be having this problem? Why isn't it default to vertical centered in the first place?!

Answer (score 18):

This does not work as expected on iOS7. On iOS7 you will have to override TextField class and

```
- (void) drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect
```

method.

Like this:

```
- (void) drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [[UIColor blueColor] setFill];
    CGRect placeholderRect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, (rect.size.height- self.font.pointSize)/2, rect.size.width, self.font.pointSize);
    [[self placeholder] drawInRect:placeholderRect withFont:self.font lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment:self.textAlignment];
}
```

Works for both iOS7 and earlier versions.

Comment: Using lineHeight instead of pointSize gives a better result in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

I was using just the color, but we need to set the font as well.

This one worked for me:

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setDefaultTextAttributes:
@{
     NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor], 
     NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]
}];
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I don't know why if you didn't set the font attribute, the placeholder will be misaligned. Maybe because the placeholder font and text font is not the same. `contentVerticalAlignment` doesn't work (at least for me).

Comment: This doesn't work if you use a bigger default font size than the placeholder one.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the minimum line height using `NSParagraphStyle` was the only solution that worked for me:

```
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [self.addressBar.defaultTextAttributes[NSParagraphStyleAttributeName] mutableCopy];
style.minimumLineHeight = self.addressBar.font.lineHeight - (self.addressBar.font.lineHeight - placeholderFont.lineHeight) / 2.0;

self.addressBar.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Placeholder text" attributes:@{
     NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor colorWithRed:79/255.0f green:79/255.0f blue:79/255.0f alpha:0.5f],
     NSFontAttributeName : placeholderFont,
     NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : style
}];
```