# How to rtl UITextField in cell with xib file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield, xib

I create a project and I create UITableview class .
I using UITextField in cell of UITableView. now I want show this UITextfield right alignment but I dont know about it.

please guide me about it.
thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

```
textfield.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
```

Hope this helps you...

EDIT:

```
txtField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentRight;
```

Read this stackoverflow post: [Placeholder text not centered for UITextField created programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665385/placeholder-text-not-centered-for-uitextfield-created-programatically)

Comment: have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665385/placeholder-text-not-centered-for-uitextfield-created-programatically

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for this:-

```
textfield.contentHorizontalAlignment =  UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentRight
```