# UITextfields placeholder fonts are not fixing at horizontal center position using HelveticaNeueLTPro-Roman font

Tags: ios, objective-c, uifont

I am new for ios and in my app I have added some textfields ok that's fine but when I apply custom fonts to this textfields then textfields placeholders are not fitting at horizontal center position

why this problem occurring please help me someone and see my below screen what I have faced here problem

### my code:

```
 [username setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeueLTPro-Roman" size:12.0]];

 [password setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeueLTPro-Roman" size:12.0]];
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Placeholder text not centered for UITextField created programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665385/placeholder-text-not-centered-for-uitextfield-created-programatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forget two simple steps

- go to your `Attribute` panel in `Xcode` and change the control alignement as `Center` and `Left`, for example like this

  [image]
- at the same time change your font type as `System` to `Custom` , for example like this [This is optional]

  [image]
- you get output like

  [image]