# IOS align text placeholder to be in the center and left alignment

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, placeholder

I'm creating an IOS form that submits feed back.

I want to have placeholder text to be in the center vertically and left alignment horizontal in the text field

I have tried this

```
- (void)drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [RGB(36, 84, 157) setFill];

    UIFont *font = [UIFont SingPostLightItalicFontOfSize:_placeholderFontSize fontKey:kSingPostFontOpenSans];
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName: font,
                                  NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle,
                                  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor]};
    [[self placeholder] drawInRect:rect withAttributes:attributes];

}
```

But the place holder text is on top vertical. How can we achieve the gold. Thanks a lot

[image]

Comment: What is the  value of `rect` is it covering the whole height of the control ? or just the one line height of the placeholder text ?

Comment: hi rect is the frame of the hold textfield

Comment: Wouldn't using auto layout, `UITextField` and UITextField's `placeholder` property be easier ? UITextField already aligns the text vertically centered for you. Inner drop shadow will be a problem though, I don't know how to generate inner drop shadow, I know how to generate outer drop shadows using code.

Comment: Hi it an old project which dont have storyboard or nib. All in code. - (void)drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect is method in textfield

Comment: You don't need to use storyboard or nib to do autolayout. You can do it purely in code.

Comment: Please check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3665442/3378413

Comment: Thanks but i tried self.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
inside (void)drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect but still not work

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694411/text-inset-for-uitextfield

Comment: I ended up by math calculation like this CGSize textSize = [self.placeholder sizeWithAttributes:attributes];
    CGFloat hdif = rect.size.height - textSize.height;
    hdif = MAX(0, hdif);
    rect.origin.y += ceil(hdif/2.0); [[self placeholder] drawInRect:rect withAttributes:attributes];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will solve your problem. I tried it myself. It's just one additional line to your code.

```
- (void)drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect {

       CGFloat fontSize = 18;
       UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize];
       NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
       paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
       paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

       NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName: font,
                              NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle,
       NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor]};

       CGRect newRect = CGRectInset(rect, 0, rect.size.height/2 - fontSize/2);
       [[super placeholder] drawInRect:newRect withAttributes:attributes];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that solve the problem. Do you think subclass the textfield is there way for default textfield to achieve the same result?

Comment: I think it is, you can simply use `attributedPlaceholder` property of `UITextField`. Do give it a try once :)

Answer (score 0):

You can put placeholder's "y" position means your "rect" value as a textfield height/2 .One more solution if you use default property of textfield for placeholder that would be horizontally aligned .

like as :

```
var tt : UITextField
        tt.placeholder = ""
```

Comment: Hi can you explain a bit more detail how we can implement that? Thanks

Comment: How are you using your textfield through storyboard or programmatically  ?.

Comment: I'm using programatically (inherit old project)

Comment: Where you are calling your function - (void)drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect {

Comment: just make your rect value like this

Comment: var drect = CGRect(x: (w * 0.25),y: textfield.frame.size.height/2: (w * 0.5),height: (h * 0.5))

Comment: i'm create a subclass of UITextFied and implement the function