# How to center vertically attributed text (custom placeholder font) in UITextField?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am using attributed text property to set custom placeholder font in UITExtfield. But my placeholder text is not vertically centered.[Here is preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEkUu.png)

```
        let font = UIFont(name: Font.myFont.name, size: 15)!
        let attributes = [
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.cadetGrey,
            NSFontAttributeName: font
        ]

        exampleTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Example Placeholder",
                                                                  attributes: attributes)
```

I tried to add

```
let centeredParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
centeredParagraphStyle.alignment = .center
```

to attribute still no luck. I also tried to use SizeToFit() on my UITextBox but no luck at all

Comment: `.alignment = .center`, that's for left/right/center, horizontal alignment, not vertical one. Check that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665385/placeholder-text-not-centered-for-uitextfield-created-programmatically `contentVerticalAlignment`

Comment: Did you figure this out? If yes, please post the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**This worked for me in Swift 5:**

```
let unitText = NSAttributedString(string: "\(unit)", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: MyColors.doveGray, NSAttributedString.Key.baselineOffset:2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
let centeredParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
centeredParagraphStyle.alignment = .center

let attributes: [String : Any] = [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: centeredParagraphStyle]
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried that already, forgot in post to put line where i put that style in attributes together with rest of attributes. Still no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

This is will set both `placeholder` and text input by user in center.

```
 exampleTextField.textAlignment = .center
```

To center both `vertically` and `horizontally`.

```
exampleTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.center

exampleTextField.textAlignment = .center
```

OR

This is will only set `placeholder` in center whereas the text input by user will remain at it's default position i.e `left align`

```
let font = UIFont(name: Font.myFont.name, size: 15)!

 let centeredParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
 centeredParagraphStyle.alignment = .center

 // add attribute of NSMutableParagraphStyle
 let attributes = [
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.gray,
            NSFontAttributeName: font,
            NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: centeredParagraphStyle
        ]

 exampleTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Example Placeholder",
                                                                    attributes: attributes)
```

Comment: My placeholder needs to be centered verticaly. You can see on picture that placeholder is near top, not in the middle